# Adding a new field inside an already implemented Axis request

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I will try to explain that briefly.

I need to include a new field called **shipToStoreGLN** inside an Axis request implemented long ago using a WSDL descriptor.

It has to appear in the path OrderRequest -> PedidosIn(OrdersIn) -> Pedido (Order)-> Cabecera (Header)

I tryed to add the field like any other field is added, but it doesn't work, it doesn't appear in the final request.

Which is even stranger is that there's another field called **shipToStore** which has the added added to the class but it's not added in the types description but it appears on the final request.

Can someone tell me how to add that field, and if possible, explain why that other field appears?

I'll paste the code, a stub of how the request has to look like and how does it looks right now.

Thanks to everybody.

The relevant **code** of the class **OrderRequestPedidosInPedidoCabecera.java** (I'm not able to copy the full java source because it's too long):

```
//The getters and setters
public java.lang.String getShipToStoreGLN() {
    return shipToStoreGLN;
}

public void setShipToStoreGLN(java.lang.String shipToStoreGLN) {
    this.shipToStoreGLN = shipToStoreGLN;
}

//Applying it to the type descriptor
elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
elemField.setFieldName("shipToStoreGLN");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://tempuri.org/GatewayService/", "shipToStoreGLN"));
elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
elemField.setNillable(false);
typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
```

The Stub on how the request has to look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gat="http://tempuri.org/GatewayService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gat:OrderRequest>
         <gat:PedidosIn>
            <gat:Identificacion>
               <gat:IdUsuario>?</gat:IdUsuario>
               <gat:Password>?</gat:Password>
            </gat:Identificacion>
            <gat:Pedido>
               <gat:Cabecera>
                  <gat:NumeroPedido>?</gat:NumeroPedido>
                  <gat:shipToStore>?</gat:shipToStore>
                  <gat:shipToStoreGLN>?</gat:shipToStoreGLN>
                  <gat:FechaPedido>?</gat:FechaPedido>
                  <gat:Facturacion>
                     <gat:Nombre>?</gat:Nombre>
                     <gat:Apellidos>?</gat:Apellidos>
                     <gat:Direccion>?</gat:Direccion>
                     <gat:CodigoPostal>?</gat:CodigoPostal>
                     <gat:Poblacion>?</gat:Poblacion>
                     <gat:Provincia>?</gat:Provincia>
                     <gat:NIF>?</gat:NIF>
                     <gat:Telefono>?</gat:Telefono>
                  </gat:Facturacion>
                  <gat:Entrega>
                     <gat:Nombre>?</gat:Nombre>
                     <gat:Apellidos>?</gat:Apellidos>
                     <gat:Direccion>?</gat:Direccion>
                     <gat:CodigoPostal>?</gat:CodigoPostal>
                     <gat:Poblacion>?</gat:Poblacion>
                     <gat:Provincia>?</gat:Provincia>
                     <gat:NIF>?</gat:NIF>
                     <gat:Telefono>?</gat:Telefono>
                  </gat:Entrega>
                  <gat:Total>?</gat:Total>
                  <gat:Email>?</gat:Email>
                  <gat:CodigoTrackingTrans>?</gat:CodigoTrackingTrans>
                  <gat:NumeroExpedicion>?</gat:NumeroExpedicion>
                  <gat:CodigoRuta>?</gat:CodigoRuta>
                  <gat:NombreRuta>?</gat:NombreRuta>
                  <gat:CodigoAgenciaDestino>?</gat:CodigoAgenciaDestino>
                  <gat:NombreAgenciaDestino>?</gat:NombreAgenciaDestino>
               </gat:Cabecera>
               <gat:Lineas>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <gat:Linea>
                     <gat:IdPedidoLinea>?</gat:IdPedidoLinea>
                     <gat:Referencia>?</gat:Referencia>
                     <gat:ReferenciaMS>?</gat:ReferenciaMS>
                     <gat:Posicion>?</gat:Posicion>
                     <gat:Cantidad>?</gat:Cantidad>
                     <gat:Descripcion>?</gat:Descripcion>
                     <gat:PrecioUnitario>?</gat:PrecioUnitario>
                     <gat:Total>?</gat:Total>
                  </gat:Linea>
               </gat:Lineas>
            </gat:Pedido>
         </gat:PedidosIn>
      </gat:OrderRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How the request looks like now:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <OrderRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/GatewayService/">
        <PedidosIn>
            <Identificacion>
                <IdUsuario>MMKTTEST</IdUsuario>
                <Password>H23mLu3RieDr</Password>
            </Identificacion>
            <Pedido>
                <Cabecera>
                    <NumeroPedido>000123657</NumeroPedido>
                    <FechaPedido>20140911 122523</FechaPedido>
                    <CodigoTiendaFacturacion>E290</CodigoTiendaFacturacion>
                    <CodigoTiendaEntrega>E290</CodigoTiendaEntrega>
                    <Facturacion>
                        <Nombre>Cristina</Nombre>
                        <Apellidos>Franco</Apellidos>
                        <Direccion>barcelona,gggg gggg</Direccion>
                        <CodigoPostal>08022</CodigoPostal>
                        <Poblacion>BARCELONA</Poblacion>
                        <Provincia>BARCELONA</Provincia>
                        <CodigoProvincia>08</CodigoProvincia>
                        <NIF>52173198K</NIF>
                        <Telefono>677714997</Telefono>
                        <pais>es</pais>
                    </Facturacion>
                    <Entrega>
                        <Nombre>MEDIA MARKT DIAGONAL MAR-BARCELONA VIDEO-TV-HIFI-E</Nombre>
                        <Apellidos>LEKTRO-COMPUTER-FOTO, S.A </Apellidos>
                        <Direccion>C.C DIAGONAL MAR AVDA DIAGONAL N&#xBA;3, planta B local 14000</Direccion>
                        <CodigoPostal>08019</CodigoPostal>
                        <Poblacion>BARCELONA</Poblacion>
                        <Provincia>BARCELONA</Provincia>
                        <NIF/>
                        <Telefono>934857200</Telefono>
                        <direccion1>C.C DIAGONAL MAR AVDA DIAGONAL N&#xBA;3, planta B local 14000</direccion1>
                        <direccion2/>
                        <direccion3/>
                    </Entrega>
                    <Total>219.0</Total>
                    <Email>crisfrancob@gmail.com</Email>
                    <CodigoTrackingTrans/>
                    <NumeroExpedicion/>
                    <CodigoRuta/>
                    <NombreRuta/>
                    <CodigoAgenciaDestino/>
                    <NombreAgenciaDestino/>
                    <shipToStore>1</shipToStore>
                </Cabecera>
                <Lineas>
                    <Linea>
                        <IdPedidoLinea>0</IdPedidoLinea>
                        <Referencia>B99B329</Referencia>
                        <ReferenciaMS>1148842</ReferenciaMS>
                        <ReferenciaUni/>
                        <Posicion>1</Posicion>
                        <Cantidad>1.0</Cantidad>
                        <Descripcion>GF EN210 SILENT/DI/1GD3/V2     CTLR 1GB DDR3 PCI-E DVI-I  HDMI       IN</Descripcion>
                        <PrecioUnitario>0.0</PrecioUnitario>
                        <Total>0.0</Total>
                    </Linea>
                </Lineas>
            </Pedido>
        </PedidosIn>
    </OrderRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: The relevant **code** (I'm not able to paste the full java source because it's too long):

Answer (score 0):

I was setting a **null** on  **shipToStoreGLN** field. Now I know you can't set a **null** and expect the XML tag to appear.